# Ошибка Android Studio с Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Работаю в Android Studio уже много месяцев, а в последнее время каждый раз при создании нового проекта происходит ошибка.

```
ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon
```

... бла-бла-бла и причина:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

Я не могу понять причину появления этой проблемы, почему раньше ее не было. Почему при создании пустого проекта уже появляются проблемы с памятью..? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Может, можно что-то сделать, чтобы она не возникала вовсе каждый раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря [Andrew Goroshko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238742/andrew-goroshko) и тем ответам, которые он нашел и на на которые сослался, у меня получилось искоренить ошибку.

Итак, вот что в итоге помогло мне. Если проблема появляется каждый раз при создании проекта:

1. Если у вас 64-х-разрядная Windows, то проверяем путь к jdk.
   В переменных средах ищем JAVA_HOME и присваиваем ему `C:\Program Files\Java\$ВЕРСИЯ`. ВЕРСИЮ можно посмотреть непосредственно в Проводнике по тому же пути.
2. В Android Studio проверяем путь через `File > Project Structure > JDK Location` и тоже изменяем на ту же C:\Program Files\Java\$ВЕРСИЯ.

В моем случае до этого путь шел через C:\Program Files(x86).

Надеюсь, это кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 5):

Для того чтобы увеличить память в проекте:

1. Перейдите в файл `gradle.properties`
2. В конце вставьте строку:

   ```
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
   ```

Должно помочь. Если же нет, то есть второй вариант:

1. Закройте проект и перейдите на стартовую страницу.
2. Перейдите в настройки: `Configure > Settings`.
3. Дальше по следуйте по такому пути: `Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler`
4. Установите: `Build process heap size (Mbytes)` до 1024 и `Additional build process to VM Options` до -Xmx512m.
5. Закройте настройки и перезагрузите AS.

### UPDATE

Если у вас Windows 64 битная, то я бы вам советовал проверить путь к jdk, так как иногда Android Studio не хватает 32 битной версии. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415411/9363441) есть ссылка для решения.

Comment: Не работает, ошибка все так же появляется... (

Comment: Уточню: первый способ помогает для каждого отдельного проекта. Но это нужно каждый раз прописывать эту строку. Второй способ не работает, ошибка все так же появляется при каждом создании проекта

Comment: посмотрите нашел еще одну причину, может проблема в разрядности jdk, это довольно распространенная ситуация.

Comment: если не поможет последний способ, то отпишитесь и будем дальше искать)

Comment: Помог! Спасибо вам большое. Тут нужно было применить много чего в комплексе из разных ответов, думаю это скомпоновать в один алгоритм для тех, кто будет просматривать этот вопрос в будущем.